# 複数のクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンスの併用について

Tags: ライセンス

プログラミングの技術文章を書いているのですが、書いた文章のライセンスについて質問させてください。  
プログラミングの技術文章には、ソースコードとソースコードに対する解説文章や図表などが含まれますが、それぞれに別々のライセンスをつけたいと考えています。

ソースコード: CC0（Public domain）
解説文章や図表: CC-BY

ソースコードにはGPLやMITなどのライセンスがありますが、ここでは再配布時に著作権を表示不要なCC0（Public Domain）をつけたいと考えています。
一方文章や図表には、著作権表示が必要なCC-BYライセンスをつけたいと考えています。

この場合、ライセンスはどのように記載したらよいのでしょうか？  
そもそもこのようなライセンスのつけ方は認めてられないのでしょうか？
ライセンスに関して最近学び始めたばかりであまり詳しいことが分かっていないので、ご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

その技術文書、およびソースコードに適切なライセンスを明記すれば良いと思います。次はGo言語の例ですが、ウェブサイトの内容（文章と図表）はCC3.0、ソースコードはBSDライセンスであることが明記されています。

> Except as noted, the content of this page is licensed under the
>   Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, and code is licensed under a
>   BSD license.

https://golang.org/ （フッターに記述があります）
https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/master/LICENSE （ソースコードレポジトリ内のLICENSEファイル）

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。
具体的な例まで教えていただき、大変参考になりました。